# Is there a way to obtain a circuit of some sort given a Nyquist plot?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory

I have some transfer functions and I was wondering if it would be possible to approximate this to an electric circuit equivalent. For example, given the Nyquist plot below, is it acceptable to hypothesise that a circuit with RC components can represent this Nyquist plot since we know that the Nyquist plot of a low pass (RC) filter is circular such as the one below?

[image]

Comment: For purposes of synthesizing a circuit from a function, a Bode plot would be easier to start with. You should be able to convert your Nyquist plot to a Bode plot.  Once you have the Bode plot, you basically have the list of poles and zeros.  From there it's relatively easy to synthesize a circuit.

Comment: @OlinLathrop say i have the following transfer function H(s) = (s - 1) / (s^2 + 4s + 4), from that i have a zero at s=1 & double poles at s=-2.  The bode plot of this resembles a second order low pass filter. Should i just then assume the circuit has the form of a second order low pass i.e. Two RC stages?

Comment: There isn't a unique solution to this general problem. There are many different circuits that have the same transfer function. It is usually easier to invent an active circuit rather than a purely passive one, because the active elements can isolate the input and output impedance of each part of the filter.